# Setting absolute position in prerender()

Tags: java, jsf, web-controls

Im completely new to Java web stuff, but here goes my question:

1) How can I add new controls to a JSF page (webuijsf) in the prerender() function?
2) How can I change the position of elements already added using the visual designer? Also in prerender().

I have a number of input fields + labels to show, coming from a database.  So I imagine I read from the database and add the appropriate number of controls during prerender.  There's also a grid below these dynamically added controls, which I'd like to move further down at the same time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to write [your own component](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/Hifaces20/Dynamic+Faces+-+sample+demonstrating+dynamic+or+programmatic+UI+creation+with+JSF+2.0+and+Facelets) if you wished to render forms based on database data. You should position your grid using [standard html](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) techniques or writing your own custom grid component.

Comment: So I cannot, for instance, add a number of labels using Java code?  I have to add them via the designer or in the JSP tree structure?

Comment: You could write a component which added n number of labels, so instead of <h:outputLabel> you would use your own tag eg.<my:dynamicForm> which would generate n label tags based on whatever code you write.